# Serial Port missing incoming bytes in Windows 10

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm reading data from a serial port that continously sends data after a start command was send. I'm working with a very high baudrate of 1408000 and a sample rate of 2000. I have to process the incoming data in the following way: 2 start bytes (0xAA, 0x55) followed by 68 bytes of real data.
Running the program in Win 7 is not a problem, but running it in Win 10 results in some missing bytes - sometimes I get e.g. only 20 bytes of data, sometimes I get 72 (always changing values). Am I missing something?

Here is my code:

```
SerialPort m_serialPort = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM8");
private static System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
private static ConcurrentQueue<List<byte>> incomingdataQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<List<byte>>();
private static readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim locker = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
static bool isProcessing = false;
private static List<byte> sampleData = new List<byte>();

public Form1()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        timer.Interval = 250;//250ms
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        m_serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        SetComConnectParam("COM8");

        if (!ComOpen()){UpdateStatus("Problem!\n");}           

        init_System(gain, sample, trigger); // sends a signal to the port to init the system
        UpdateStatus("start data recording " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Start_Data(); // sends a signal to the port to start data processing
        timer.Start();
}

public void SetComConnectParam(string portName, int baudRate = 1408000)
{            
    m_serialPort.PortName = portName;
    m_serialPort.BaudRate = baudRate;
    m_serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
    m_serialPort.DataBits = 8;
    m_serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;                     
}

private bool ComOpen()
{
    // Closing serial port if it is open
    if (m_serialPort != null && m_serialPort.IsOpen){m_serialPort.Close();}

    if (false == m_serialPort.IsOpen)
    {
        try
        {
            m_serialPort.Open();
            m_serialPort.DiscardInBuffer(); 
        }
        catch { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}

private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort comport = sender as SerialPort;
    if (comport == null || comport.BytesToRead == 0 || !comport.IsOpen) { return; }

    int dataLength = comport.BytesToRead;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[dataLength];
    int nbrDataRead = comport.Read(buffer, 0, dataLength);
    if (nbrDataRead == 0) { return; }
    incomingdataQueue.Enqueue(buffer.Take(nbrDataRead).ToList());
}

void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (incomingdataQueue.Count == 0) { return; }
    ProcessData();
}

private void ProcessData()
{
    int byteperdatasample = 68;
    if (incomingdataQueue.Count == 0) { return; }
    if (!locker.TryEnterWriteLock(100)) { return; }
    if (isProcessing)
    {
        locker.ExitWriteLock();
        return;
    }
    isProcessing = true;
    List<byte> currentData = new List<byte>();
    while (incomingdataQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        incomingdataQueue.TryDequeue(out currentData);
        for (int i = 0; i < currentData.Count; i++)
        {
            // problem: startseq is 0xAA, 0x55. 0xAA might be last entry in         currentData list and 0x55 might be first entry in next data list
            if (i == currentData.Count - 1 && currentData[i].Equals(170)) { startIndex = -99; startFound = false; }
            if (i == 0 && currentData[i].Equals(85))
            {
                if (startIndex.Equals(-99)){startFound = true;}
                else{startFound = false;}
            }
            if (i < currentData.Count - 1 && currentData[i].Equals(170) && currentData[i + 1].Equals(85))
            {
               startFound = true;
               startIndex = i;
            }
            if (startFound)
            {
                if (startIndex == -99){sampleData.RemoveAt(sampleData.Count - 1);}//remove latest item (first start item 0xaa was added in last currentData list)

                if (sampleData.Count == byteperdatasample)//
                {
                /* whole block of data processing */
                }
                else{//error}
            else
            {
                if (i != startIndex + 1){sampleData.Add(currentData[i]);}
            }
        }
    }
    isProcessing = false;
    locker.ExitWriteLock();
}

private void ButtonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stop_Data();
    timer.Stop();
}
```

Comment: I would guess concurrent access. You protect the queue against reentrant access, but not against concurrent access via DataReceived and ProcessData.

Comment: Unrelated: closing the port and opening immediately after most probably won't work if it was in fact open. The OS needs some time to "clean up".

Comment: At second sight, I am even more confused. ProcessData never seems to consume `incomingdataQueue` and `currentData` never seems to get added to?? `locker` doesn't seem to be declared anywhere... Am I missing something?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to copy these lines. added with edit. I wasn't sure if I even have to protect the queue with a locker because it already is a ConcurrentQueue.

Comment: It is a concurrent queue, yes. But what does that mean? It means, that no ConcurrentAccessException is thrown if two Thread are trying to access the queue at the same time and the queue manages access, so operations happen in a "happen-before" manner. That does _not_ mean that two adjacent calls on one thread happen uninterrupted by a third on another thread. What does _that_ mean? Example: Thread 1: queue.Count => 5, Thread 2: queue.Clear , Thread 1: queue.Dequeue => queue is empty, although Thread 1 "thinks" there must be 5 elements. That is what this means and why you need additional sync.

Comment: what really makes me wonder: the error occurs always at the beginning e.g. within the first 5000 samples and than it works fine for a very long period. Sometimes the error occurs again after this, sometimes not. In Win 7 I don't have those problems.

Comment: This only ever worked by accident on the old machine, benefiting from it being slower and thus being able to receive more bytes before the event handler could be called.  How many bytes you'll read is fundamentally unpredictable, be sure to keep calling Read() until you got all the bytes in the "message".   Intentionally use a low baud rate to get confident that the code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

May be try working without timer 
add new Task  if (incomingdataQueue.Count == 0) { return; }
                  Task.Run(()=>ProcessData()); in DataReceivedHandler handler.

```
 private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort comport = sender as SerialPort;
            if (comport == null || comport.BytesToRead == 0 || !comport.IsOpen) { return; }

            int dataLength = comport.BytesToRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[dataLength];
            int nbrDataRead = comport.Read(buffer, 0, dataLength);

            if (nbrDataRead == 0) { return; }
            incomingdataQueue.Enqueue(buffer.Take(nbrDataRead).ToList());

            if (incomingdataQueue.Count > 0) {
              Task.Run(()=>ProcessData());
           }
        }
```